# Efficient way to find average of values in an array of hashes grouping by another value

Tags: ruby

I'm collecting some data using some API calls.
Now I have this data

```
data = [
  {:energyCons=>0.64, :energyCons100=>64, :energyClass=>"B"},
  {:energyCons=>0.64, :energyCons100=>64, :energyClass=>"B"},
  {:energyCons=>0.64, :energyCons100=>64, :energyClass=>"B"},
  {:energyCons=>0.64, :energyCons100=>64, :energyClass=>"B"},
  {:energyCons=>0.64, :energyCons100=>64, :energyClass=>"B"}
]
```

I need to group by `energyClass` and then get the average for `energyCons` and `energyCons100`

Basically, I need a simple array with

```
["B": {energyCons: 0.74, energyCons100: 82}, "C": {energyCons: 0.74, energyCons100: 82}.... ]
```

where the key is the energy class I group and the value is a hash with the two averages.

I can do that but only with multiple loops, is there any compact way?

Comment: There's no `energyClass` C in `data`, can you check that?

Comment: whats your current approach to achieve it?

Comment: @Therussianshame the array has about 10.000 records with energy class from A to F

Comment: @Masroor i fill an array with all the energy classes, then I create an array for every class and then I average the values of the arrays

Comment: @RobertoPezzali your example would be much better if you had different energy classes in your input (e.g. "B" and "C") with different values and an output matching your input (in terms of calculated averages). Also, show your attempt, even if it is cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first group `data` by every element's `energyClass` value and then do the proper calculation;

```
data
  .group_by { |d| d[:energyClass] }
  .transform_values do |values|
    {
      energyCons: values.sum { |v| v[:energyCons] } / values.size,
      energyCons100: values.sum { |v| v[:energyCons100] } / values.size
    }
  end
```